# How to disable an SVG from duplicating on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

For reference, trying to recreate this portfolio for practice: https://brittanychiang.com/

I'm working with React and I'm trying to make this SVG change color and move up a few pixels. So far, it works. However, when I hover over the SVG, it ends up duplicating. Leaving behind the original svg while also changing the duplicates color and moving it up a few pixels.

I have tried adding a background color but no luck, doesn't seem to show.

**hover effect**

```css
.effect {
    transition: transform 1s ease,  stroke .5s ease;
}

.effect:hover {
    stroke: #64FFDA;
    transform:translateY(-10px);
}
```

**SVG animation**

```js
const SocialIcons = (props) => {
    return (
        <Icons>
            <motion.div
            initial={{transform:"scale(0)"}}
            animate={{scale:[0,1]}}
            transition={{type:'spring', duration:1, delay:1}}
            >
                <NavLink style={{color:'inherit'}}  target="_blank"   to={{pathname:"https://github.com/SiriusVisuals"}}>
                    <Github class="effect" width={20} height={20} />
                </NavLink>
            </motion.div>
            <motion.div
            initial={{transform:"scale(0)"}}
            animate={{scale:[0,1]}}
            transition={{type:'spring', duration:1, delay:1.4}}
            >
                <NavLink style={{color:'inherit'}}  target="_blank"   to={{pathname:"https://www.linkedin.com/in/taylenschmaltz/"}}>
                    <LinkedIn class="effect" width={20} height={20} />
                </NavLink>
            </motion.div>

            <Line color={props.theme}

initial={
    {
        height:0
    }
}
animate={{
    height: '8rem'
}}
transition={{
    type:'spring', duration:1, delay:0.8
}}
            />
        </Icons>
    )
}

export default SocialIcons
```

**SVG data**

```js
export const LinkedIn = (props) => {
  return (
    <svg
      aria-hidden="true"
      data-prefix="fas"
      data-icon="link"
      className="feather feather-linkedin"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke-width="2"
      fill="none"
      role="img"
      stroke="currentColor"
      stroke-linecap="round"
    
      {...props}
    >
      <path
        d="M16 8a6 6 0 0 1 6 6v7h-4v-7a2 2 0 0 0-2-2 2 2 0 0 0-2 2v7h-4v-7a6 6 0 0 1 6-6z"
      />
      <rect x="2" y="9" width="4" height="12"></rect>
      <circle cx="4" cy="4" r="2"></circle>
    </svg>
  );
};
```

[Here you can see my SVG duplicating.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRESG.png)

I added more info, honestly, nothing outside of this is relevant. SVG data shows what contents belong to "LinkedIn". SVG animation refers to the icons loading into the webpage on initial load. Also shows the dedicated path, and defined width/height. Finally, the hover effect shows what I applied to have this SVG change colors and move up a few pixels.

Comment: please provide a little bit more html. so we can see the container around it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added more details, please let me know if there are any more questions. I've applied everything relevant though.